# Using Authlogic in a non-Rails environment

Tags: ruby, authlogic

What would be the best way to use Authlogic in a non-Rails environment? In other words, how to validate credentials from within a Ruby script?

When run from console, `self` refers to a "main" `Object`, hence Authlogic initialization is pointless:

```
2.3.1 :009 > Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
```

It expects to be initialized with a controller, because it needs `request` and `ip` and probably other stuff. This is very strange to see, because `UserSession` is a model and should not be coupled with a controller.

Any suggestions on how to validate credentials?

Comment: Check out `lib/authlogic/test_case.rb` which uses a mock controller.